# How do I build simple boost program on Mac OS (Lion)

Tags: boost, osx-lion

Steps: 
 1. sudo port boost 
The boost file installed in /opt/local/boost, library files are in /opt/local/lib 

 2. use XCode to create c++ project

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
int main () {
    return 0;
}
```

3. set XCode to find out boost
in "Build Settings" -> "HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS" 
in both Debug and Release add path /opt/local/include

 
4.  "Build Settings" -> "LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS" --> add /opt/local/lib both for debug and release.

5. build program and failed. 
Error Messages,

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::system::generic_category()", referenced from:
  ___cxx_global_var_init1 in main.o
  ___cxx_global_var_init2 in main.o
  "boost::system::system_category()", referenced from:
  ___cxx_global_var_init3 in main.o
  boost::asio::error::get_system_category() in main.o
  "boost::asio::error::get_netdb_category()", referenced from:
  ___cxx_global_var_init5 in main.o <br>
  "boost::asio::error::get_addrinfo_category()", referenced from:
  ___cxx_global_var_init6 in main.o <br>
  "boost::asio::error::get_misc_category()", referenced from:
  ___cxx_global_var_init7 in main.o <br>
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Am I wrong in the procedure?

Comment: This seems to be more like a question how to link against a library in a project properly. Path is not enough, but the library also has to be specified.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to link with `Boost.System`, which should be in `/opt/local/lib/libboost_system` (with some suffix, that depends on how you built boost)

Add that to your Xcode project.

Comment: This is correct despite the lack of acceptance.  I spaced that in the docs but sure enough it's [right here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio/using.html#boost_asio.using.dependencies).

Comment: How do you add something in /opt to your XCode project? /opt is an invisible folder.

Comment: @WarrenP I drag /opt/ folder into lefeside of the finder as shortcut. I also show all the hidden files but also cannot show in Xcode library linking panel.

Comment: Wait, does that mean Asio is compiled within libboost_system ? I can't seem to find a libboost_asio file after installing boost, yet when I link with boost_system, asio symbols are missing.

Comment: Version i'm using which is `XCode Version 6.4 (6E35b)` what I did is I've just made a symbolic link from brew installation of boost with `ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.58.0 ~/boost` which makes it easily accessible. 

Then you click on `project` icon in the left hand side menu, then target, build phases and link binary with libraries. Press the little plus sign and choose libboost_system-mt.dylib and libboost_thread-mt.dylib. That linked the libraries and allowed successful build with asio library included. Edit: Just realised that was the second answer

Answer (score 4):

1. select on your "targets"
2. in "Link Binary with libraries" section under "build phases" tab, add boost library.
3. if install via MacPort, the boost will be at `/opt/local/lib`,
   if install via brew, the boost will be at `/usr/local/Cellar/boost` ,
   if build by yourself, it will be at `/usr/local/lib by default` or `yourBoostLib/stage/lib`